# Unexpected evaluation path

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a simple batch script. The problem is that it always executes the `:rand` block of code.

Here is the script:

```
@echo off
ver
echo %COMSPEC%

IF "%1"=="" goto help
IF "%1"=="h" goto help
IF "%1"=="-h" goto help
IF "%1"=="help" goto help
IF "%1"=="-help" goto help

IF %1=="-random" goto rand
IF %1=="-eval" goto eval

:rand
echo %@RANDOM[-10,10]
goto end

:eval 
echo %@eval[%2]
goto end

:help
echo Program sluzy do korzystania z funkcji @RANDOM @EVAL
echo aby skorzystac z @RANDOM, prosze uruchomic program z argumentem -random
echo aby skorzystac z @EVAL, prosze uruchomic program z argumentem -eval
goto end

:end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put quotes around `%1`

Comment: The IF command is a STRING comparison.  Everything on the left side of the comparison operator must also be on the right of the comparison operator for the statement to be TRUE.

Comment: You should also probably have a `goto end` right before the `:rand` to prevent fallthrough in the event that the value passed to the batch file does not match any of your tests.